# Current C11 Implementation Status (<threads.h>)?

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, posix, c11

I'm curious what the status of C11 implementations are, specifically in regard to the optional `<threads.h>`.  Do any platforms currently support the interfaces?  If not, are there any plans to implement the interfaces in terms of POSIX and/or WinAPI?

Is anyone else planning on using the interfaces described in C11 (`thrd_t`, `mtx_t`, `cond_t`, etc...)?

Comment: In general.  Linux, `x`BSD, OSX, Windows, etc...

Comment: Pelles C for Windows has complete c11 support.

Comment: I have implemented these features as shallow macros on top of POSIX threads in P99 (p99.gforge.inria.fr). So you don't have to wait for the compiler/library implementors to provide them for you. On Windows, there is the commercial library that was at the origin of the specification from the start (and for which I forgot the name.)

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status: _ISO C11 support is now at a similar level of completeness to ISO C99 support._

Comment: @nosid, if you look at the last entry, there, you'd just see that the threading part is not implemented, since it is mainly a library issue.

Comment: @JensGustedt I also implemented a version of the `<threads.h>` interface using `pthreads`.  It's mostly a one-to-one mapping, but it's probably not something I'd consider submitting as a patch for any of the platforms.  I guess the consensus is 'if you're on a platform that relies on POSIX (Linux, BSD, OSX, etc...), you should plan to use a non-distribution [version](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr), write your own, or just use `pthreads`'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does any C library implement C11 threads for GNU/Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557728/does-any-c-library-implement-c11-threads-for-gnu-linux)