# Does any C library implement C11 threads for GNU/Linux?

Tags: c, multithreading, c11

There have been ***a lot*** of questions about C11 and C11 threading, but I don't see a definitive answer anywhere:

**Does *any* C library implement the C11 threading interface usable on GNU/Linux-like?** e.g., provide the "optional" `<threads.h>` and the [thread support library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread) like `thrd_create()`, from [the C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) near p. 376.

Ideally, I'd like to find a library that is common-ish, open-source or free, for common/generic/multi architecture (e.g., GNU/Linux, x86_64, or portable-ish).

A few of the more helpful and relevant SO links:

- [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859394/c11-thread-h-in-gcc) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875545/c11-gcc-threads-h-not-found) on `glibc`;
- [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876043/multi-threading-support-in-c11) that's talking about the standard;
- [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244153/clang-c11-threads-h-not-found) about `clang`;
- [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804594/compilers-that-support-c11) about C11 in general and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400686/current-c11-implementation-status-threads-h) about Windows and other platforms;
- a lot more about *C++11* threading, but I am only interested in C11.

Some non-starter options for libraries:

- [`glibc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/libc.html) library [does not](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status); there is an [open bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14092) since 2012; there was [GSoC proposal](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2014-02/msg00781.html) but seems [not accepted](http://www.google-melange.com/gsoc/projects/list/google/gsoc2014);
- [LLVM/Clang](http://llvm.org) project does not have a C library;
- <strike>[musl](http://wiki.musl-libc.org/wiki/Compatibility) library [does not](http://nsz.repo.hu/git/?p=musl-tables;a=blob_plain;f=tab_c11.html;hb=HEAD);</strike> -- now does! See edit below and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28412024/3562032).
- [Newlib](http://sourceware.org/newlib/) library supports threading ([docs](http://sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html)), but not using `pthread` nor C11 threads;
- [uClibc](http://www.uclibc.org) does not;
- [this comparison](http://www.etalabs.net/compare_libcs.html) chart, which is dubious (e.g., I see no evidence in musl sources for C11 thread-local storage support);
- Some various posts about [BSD](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTI5Nzk),
- [Pelles](http://www.smorgasbordet.com/pellesc/), which appears closed and Windows-only.

I am ***not*** interested in POSIX threads (many fine options), Windows, an IDE, nor C++11 (I know that GNU `libstdc++` and LLVM/Clang `libc++` provide C++11's `std::thread`, which uses `-pthread`)

Thanks!

---

(re-)Edit: question re-opened, so [migrated content to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28412024/3562032) to clean up.

Comment: not that I have found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244153/clang-c11-threads-h-not-found

Comment: @Grady - Thanks; your question was already link #4 above. :) Empirically, for example, `glibc` sets `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` to `1` as you note in your question.

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't click through enough.

Comment: @Grady - No worries; your question (from 1+ year ago!) illustrated part of the issue. My question became a bit more of a "survey paper" than I had intended, but if that is its only value, so be it.

Comment: Downvote/close care to comment? I tried to add value and summarize all current knowledge and options, to obviate digging through the 5+ other questions and sources/docs from 5+ libraries. I'd like to do better (or save my breath!) next time; please advise.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about a 6:1 ratio on what is tantamount to a tool shopping question (a well researched tool shopping question).

Comment: Just for future reference, the discussions on the musl mailing list about C11 thread support appear to be in the July, August, and September 2014 timeframes.

Comment: @hoc_age I imagine the CV is because requests to find a software library are considered off-topic.

Comment: glibc now has support, included in 2.28

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[musl](http://www.musl-libc.org) now (as of Sep 2014-ish) implements C11 threads!

According to [this recent musl mailing list post](http://www.openwall.com/lists/musl/2014/09/07/15) and other conversation on [that list in Jul-Sep 2014](http://www.openwall.com/lists/musl/), it appears that the [musl](http://wiki.musl-libc.org/wiki/Compatibility) library now (as of 2014-09-07) implements the C11 threads interface, though [the comparison chart](http://nsz.repo.hu/git/?p=musl-tables;a=blob_plain;f=tab_c11.html;hb=HEAD); does not as of this writing reflect this.

Since this question is re-opened, I moved this content to a proper answer.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried `musl-gcc figE_12.c` and was able to compile something with `<threads.h>` . I tried to on gcc, and could not. I'm using Debian stretch.  `gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516` it gave me `fatal error: threads.h: No such file or directory` I tried linking with `-threads` but just got `error: unrecognized command line option ‘-threads’; did you mean ‘-pthread’?` Anyway musi worked. Thanks i'm up voting you.

Answer (score 18):

Finally [GNU LIBC 2.28](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=NEWS;utm=anzwix;h=154ab22d7ca065af5233406927302bb7f6a66890;hb=3c03baca37fdcb52c3881e653ca392bba7a99c2b) supports C11 ISO Threads.

I assume Archlinux, Gentoo and Suse Tumbleweed will support it quickly. Later in this year Fedora and Ubuntu and the others in 2019 or later.

Comment: Awesome! Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908031/how-to-multithread-c-code/52453354#52453354

Answer (score 12):

https://github.com/jtsiomb/c11threads is a "Trivial C11 threads.h implementation over POSIX threads." contained in a single header.

Answer (score 4):

Hmmm, it looks like GCC 4.9.0 actually provides substantial support for C11 standards (at least since the web docs were modified on around the end of June, 2014.

From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Standards.html

> A fourth version of the C standard, known as C11, was published in
>   2011 as ISO/IEC 9899:2011. GCC has substantially complete support for
>   this standard, enabled with -std=c11 or -std=iso9899:2011. (While in
>   development, drafts of this standard version were referred to as C1X.)

And from https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html

> ISO C11 atomics (the _Atomic type specifier and qualifier and the
>    header) are now supported. ISO C11 generic selections
>   (_Generic keyword) are now supported. ISO C11 thread-local storage
>   (_Thread_local, similar to GNU C __thread) is now supported. ISO C11
>   support is now at a similar level of completeness to ISO C99 support:
>   substantially complete modulo bugs, extended identifiers (supported
>   except for corner cases when -fextended-identifiers is used),
>   floating-point issues (mainly but not entirely relating to optional
>   C99 features from Annexes F and G) and the optional Annexes K
>   (Bounds-checking interfaces) and L (Analyzability). A new C extension
>   __auto_type provides a subset of the functionality of C++11 auto in GNU C.

From that, it is hard to tell what all of that will really mean when the pedal hits the metal. An upgrade on an environment to the latest GCC 4.9.0 release and a few simple driver programs would confirm how much or how little it is being implemented.

Hope it helps.

Comment: gcc support is a whole different kettle of fish to glibc support, though.

Comment: Right; I am using `gcc-4.9.0` and `glibc-2.19` (believe current stable). The combination reports `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` as `1`, declaring [lack of support](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status) for the "optional" threads "feature," hence I'm looking elsewhere. :) For C *language* features and compiler-specific stuff, `gcc` supports (most of) C11 (e.g., syntax, semantics, compiler-specific headers, `libgcc` stuff). For different reasons, the `gcc` codebase bundles `libstdc++`, but `glibc` is *not* bundled in `gcc`, so C *library* stuff like `<thread.h>` and ilk are rather separate.

Answer (score 4):

FreeBSD provides `threads.h` since FreeBSD 10.0  The program needs to be linked against libstdsthreads.

Answer (score 2):

PDCLib (the Public Domain C standard library) includes AFAICT full support for threads.h, and it's not a wrapper around pthreads.

Answer (score 0):

FreeBSD seems to wrap around the posix threads.  You can find it here: 
[FreeBSD c11 threads](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/tree/master/lib/libstdthreads).  I was able to use this in Cygwin.  So far no problems but I haven't used it that much yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is [TinyCThread](https://tinycthread.github.io/) which implements the `threads.h` API of standard C11. It wraps POSIX and Windows threads. It's quite easy to integrate in your project: it consists of one `.h` and one `.c` file.