# C11 - Why <threads.h> not implemented

Tags: c, multithreading, c11

Why C11's `<threads.h>` not implemented nor in standard OS libs, nor in compiler-specific (clang, gcc)?

(For dublicate marks: Existing questions specifies what you can use instead, but not *why*.)

Comment: Short answer: it's optional. Long answer: these things take time.

Comment: Here is another duplicate that has a bit more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557728/does-any-c-library-implement-c11-threads-for-gnu-linux. In fact the threads library is implemented on Linux systems that are based on musl, e.g Alpine.